# Is a dynamic_cast<> limited to direct casts along the inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

**CODE**

```
struct A { };           // virtual details there, but left out
struct B { };           // virtual details there, but left out
struct C : A, B { };    // virtual details there, but left out

C c;
B& b = c;
A& a = dynamic_cast<A&>( b );  // will this cast succeed at run-time?
```

Note that I have left out the virtual details to keep the code simple.

If dynamic_cast<> is limited to direct casts along the inheritance hierarchy, then I expect the code above to fail at run-time (because B& is unrelated to A&).

However, if it is more generic/flexible, the code should work, because the true-type of the referred to object is of C type (and C can be referred to as B& or A&).

*What do the C++ specifications say about this case?*

Comment: This is known as a **cross cast** because it moves across the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the code won't compile because none of the classes has any virtual functions -- a requirement to use `dynamic_cast`. If you add at least one virtual function (e.g., a virtual dtor to `B`, then yes, since a `C` is derived publicly from `B`, the cast will succeed.

Here's a bit of quick demo code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual void junk() { std::cout << "A"; }
    void trash() { std::cout << "A"; }
    virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B { 
    virtual ~B(){} 
    void trash() { std::cout << "B"; }
    void junk() { std::cout << "B"; }
};

struct C : virtual A, virtual B { 
    void trash()  { std::cout << "C"; }
    void junk() { std::cout << "C"; }
};    

int main() {
    C c;
    B& b = c;
    A& a = dynamic_cast<A&>(b); 
    a.trash();
    std::cout << "\n";
    a.junk();
}
```

The output (with both VC++ and g++, and this isn't cutting edge, so I'd expect anything but a truly ancient compiler to get it right) is:

```
A
C
```

Showing that the `a` has a static type of `A`, but a dynamic type of `C`.

Comment: Interesting - that last bit on compiler optimisation - I didn't know the compiler can optimise away run-time constructs.  But it does make sense if the compiler is smart enough to know that the cast must succeed for the code as written.

Comment: @kfmfe04: The more I think about it, the less convinced I am that the compiler is likely to be able to eliminate the run-time check in this case, so I've removed that comment (but added demo code that at least shows the externally visible behavior).

Answer (score 6):

`dynamic_cast<T>(v)` may go down to the most derived object of which `v` is a sub-object, then up (possibly a different branch) to find an unambiguous base class to which `T` is a pointer or a reference. From the standard:

> **5.2.7/8** If `C` is the class type to which `T` points or refers, the run-time check logically executes as follows:
>
> - If, in the most derived object pointed (referred) to by `v`, `v` points (refers) to a public base class subobject of a `C` object, and
>     if only one object of type `C` is derived from the subobject pointed
>     (referred) to by `v` the result points (refers) to that `C` object.
> - Otherwise, if `v` points (refers) to a public base class subobject of the most derived object, and the type of the most derived object
>     has a base class, of type `C`, that is unambiguous and public, the
>     result points (refers) to the `C` subobject of the most derived
>     object.
> - Otherwise, the run-time check *fails.*