# why shouldn't these conditions work for template types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, casting

As my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366216/failing-in-trying-to-code-smart-cast-template-function/29366347) i am trying to build a conditions to examine two types check if should i do `dynamic_cast` or not.
I had following conditions:

```
#define can_dynamic_cast(FROM, TO) \
                                can_cast(FROM, TO) && \
                                !std::is_same<FROM, TO>::value && \
                                std::is_class<TO>::value && \
                                !std::is_const<FROM>::value && \ 
                                std::is_base_of<TO, FROM>::value
```

It does not work for below basic check, the `can_dynamic_cast` will return true!!!

```
 static_assert(!can_dynamic_cast(int, int), "didn't expecting dynamic cast, but could!")
```

Out of desperation i came down to below conditions, but still no hope!!

```
#define can_dynamic_cast(FROM, TO)   \
                                    std::is_convertible<FROM, TO>::value && \
                                    std::is_class<TO>::value && \
                                    std::is_class<FROM>::value
```

The above conditions are the most basic conditions, `can_dynamic_cast` will return `true` for `(int, int)` again, which is not suppose to!!!

## Question

1) What am i don't wrong?

Comment: Try expanding your macro by hand. Hint: that `!` is not being applied to the entire expression.

Comment: @Brian But the destination type must be a pointer/reference to a complete class type or a pointer to cv void.

Comment: @T.C. Whoops, you're right. I missed that.

Comment: @Brian no that was just a simple check, in real use of my codes `FROM` and `TO` can be anything, and 2 `anything` sometimes shouldn't `dynamic_cast`ed.

Comment: @T.C. You are right!! that was my mistake:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [#define not executing all arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108422/define-not-executing-all-arguments)

Comment: @AntonSavin nop dude, these are not same thing :) this was not a newbe question for why `!(condition)` works and `!condition` does not, i just missed the point as @T.C mentioned.

Comment: You're obviously familiar with template metaprogramming. So why on earth are you using macros instead?

Comment: I agree with @BenjaminLindley - you should not use a macro in the first place.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley because i am about to use it in half a thousand of template functions + it increases maintainability/readability

Comment: That doesn't sound like an argument that would favor macros over template metaprogramming. Just the opposite. That's certainly the first time I've heard anyone claim macros have easier maintainability over anything.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i don't see why? i would appreciate if you explain a bit more, why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Isn't your question evidence enough? A proper template wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley when you have a some quite template functions and in many of them its needed to check if the input type can be casted with `dynamic_cast` and you can mention it just with a `can_dynamic_cast()` instead of 4-5 line of condition checking in all of them + if sometime you have figured you have problem with your conditions, with a macro the fix can be done just with one edition, but imagine how many edition you need to do without a simple macro -- all you have to do is to code a simple macro right. just saying....

Comment: Okay, now I see the problem. You're not as familiar with template metaprogramming as I thought. You know how to use traits, but don't know how to create them yourself.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley please... :)))

Comment: The checks themselves look horribly wrong. `dynamic_cast<T>(someT)` works. It doesn't require the new type to be a base of the old type (that would be a situation better met with `static_cast`). It can convert across the hierarchy (e.g., `dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(someDerived2)` works if both are derived from the same class). I'm just confused by what these checks actually accomplish.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say something [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015309/is-a-dynamic-cast-limited-to-direct-casts-along-the-inheritance-hierarchy) for casting across the hierarchy. Ignore that part.

Comment: @chris as i [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366216/failing-in-trying-to-code-smart-cast-template-function/29366347) why `dynamic_cast` is crucial in my app. I am in early stage of creating conditions(which was very basic concept of `dynamic_cast`) , which i got errors from it, i will post the real conditions when i am done with it, for who cares.

Comment: Please? Please what? If you want an intro template metaprogramming, I would suggest watching Walter Brown's excellent talks from cppcon 2014. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i know what may you are thinking of what am i coding and **how** am i coding it. but you are wrong, i won't continue this discussion any more, it's cool

Comment: Erm... to me, it looks like @AntonSavin dupe tag was right - that was exactly what you missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the solutions and answers given in the comments: (Thanks to T.C. and AntonSavin)

Your macro is not completely wrong, but it is a macro. The preprocessor simply replaces the macro call with the content of the macro:

```
 static_assert(!can_dynamic_cast(int, int), "...");
 // =>
 static_assert(!std::is_convertible<int, int>::value && 
                std::is_class<int>::value &&
                std::is_class<int>::value , "...");
```

Thus, only the first value is negated and this produces the unexpected behavior.

To overcome this problem you have to add brackets, either in the definition of the macro, or in the call of the macro:

```
#define can_dynamic_cast(FROM, TO) \
         ( std::is_convertible<FROM, TO>::value && \
           std::is_class<TO>::value && \
           std::is_class<FROM>::value )
// or

static_assert(!(can_dynamic_cast(int, int)), "...");
```

A better solution and not much longer solution is creating an own type-traits class:

```
template <class FROM, class TO>
struct can_dynamic_cast : std::integral_constant< bool,
    std::is_convertible<FROM, TO>::value && 
    std::is_class<TO>::value &&
    std::is_class<FROM>::value > {};

static_assert(!can_dynamic_cast<int, int>::value, "...");
```

it is less error-prone, since it follows c++ syntax in the meta-function call and no additional brackets are needed.